# Taking snapshots of JavaFX TextArea and WebView

Tags: javafx, webview, textarea, snapshot

I have the following problem:
I'm writing a program that is like a blank paper where you can write on (free hand-writing), insert text, add images, add pdfs etc...
For one specific feature I need to convert the Nodes added to the Pane by the user to images. Thankfully, JavaFX-Nodes provide a nice method:

```
public void snapshot(...)
```

But there is one issue: When I'm trying to make Snapshots of text-objects they fail. The only Node that I can take snapshots of is javafx.scene.text.Text.
The following classes fail:

```
javafx.scene.control.TextArea
javafx.scene.web.WebView
```

Here is an example to illustrate my problem:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {

            TextArea textArea = new TextArea("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text"
                    + " of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been \n"
                    + "the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an \n"
                    + "unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type\n"
                    + " specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the\n"
                    + " leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It\n"
                    + " was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing\n"
                    + " Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software \n"
                    + "like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum");

            SnapshotParameters snapshotParameters = new SnapshotParameters();
            snapshotParameters.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);

            Image img = textArea.snapshot(snapshotParameters, null);
            ImageView imgVw = new ImageView( img );

            System.out.printf("img.width: %s    height: %s%n", img.getWidth(), img.getHeight()); // <= width and height of the image img is 1:1! WHY?

            Pane pane = new Pane();
            pane.getChildren().addAll(imgVw);

            Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 800,800);

            pane.setMinWidth(800);
            pane.setMinHeight(800);
            pane.setMaxWidth(800);
            pane.setMaxHeight(800);

            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I could think of a work-around by creating a javafx.scene.text.Text-Object and take a snapshot of that. But this will fail for formatted Text displayed by javafx.scene.web.WebView.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The [TextArea](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextArea.html) needs to be a [Scene](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html) before you snapshot it.  Add the following line to your code before the snapshot call and the code will work as you expect:

```
Scene snapshotScene = new Scene(textArea);
```

This requirement is mentioned in the [snapshot javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot-javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters-javafx.scene.image.WritableImage-):

> NOTE: In order for CSS and layout to function correctly, the node must
>   be part of a Scene (the Scene may be attached to a Stage, but need not
>   be).

Comment: Thank you so much! Perfect answer!